# Including Bean Name Prevents Creation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have a configuration class (see below) that creates Retrofit "beans", these beans are then (supposed to be) injected into a service. However, at this time it appears the Retrofit bean "exampleRepository" is not created prior to the service *when* bean name is provided, i.e. "@Bean(name = exampleRepository)". I've used this setup numerous other times without issue, but it is failing here. Does anyone know why? Code follows.

**Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("example")
public class RetrofitConfig {

  @NotNull
  private String baseUrl;

  public String getBaseUrl() {
    return baseUrl;
  }

  public void setBaseUrl(String baseUrl) {
    this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
  }

  @Bean(name = "retrofitBuilder")
  public Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder() {    
    return new Retrofit.Builder().addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create());
  }

  @Bean(name = "okHttpClient")
  public OkHttpClient okHttpClient() {
    HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor);
    return httpClient.build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "exampleRetrofit")
  public Retrofit exampleRetrofit(@Qualifier("retrofitBuilder") Retrofit.Builder builder, @Qualifier("okHttpClient") OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {    
    return builder.client(okHttpClient).baseUrl(getBaseUrl()).build();
  }

  @Bean(name = "exampleRepository")
  public ExampleContract exampleRespository(@Qualifier("exampleRetrofit") Retrofit retrofit) {    
    return retrofit.create(ExampleContract.class);
  }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ExampleService {

  private ExampleContract exampleRepository;

  public ExampleService(ExampleContract exampleRepository) {
    this.exampleRepository = exampleRepository;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don’t you need @Autowired annotation for exampleRepository in ExampleService?

Comment: As of Spring 4.3, since `ExampleService` is annotated with `@Service` and has only one constructor, `@Autowired` is not explicitly required.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your bean declaration 'exampleRe**s**pository'.

By default spring injects beans by its type, in your service declaration add @Qualifier for the repository declaration or correct the typo.

below is a good article on name based injection works
https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/inject-bean-by-name.html